# Is the following true of any convergent series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent (and not necessarily absolutely convergent), is it true for any choice of $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} a_n + \sum_{n=m}^{\infty} a_n$$

Comment: Is there any possible way that $\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} a_n$ is not a constant?  Is there any way that $m <  k$ that $\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} a_n + \sum_{n=m}^k a_n \ne \sum_{n=1}^k a_n$. and if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^k a_n = K$ then is is possible that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n - \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} a_n= (\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^k a_n) - \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} a_n \ne K -  \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} a_n$?

Comment: $n$ is not a free variable in that expression, so there's no sense in which its value can be 'chosen'